# regex that match amazon link and replace it

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that matches amazon links on a string and replace it with another string. The code i wrote for the moment does not work since it just substitute a part of the url. I want to substitute all the url. this is the code

```
import re
regex = r"https://amzn.to/[a-zA-Z0-9]+" + "|" + r"https://www.amazon.it/[a-zA-Z0-9]+" 

string="https://amzn.to/3Ueforw"
string1="https://www.amazon.it/dp/B08F9LM1FB/?tag=seller050-21&psc=1"
string = re.sub(regex, "URL", string)
string1 = re.sub(regex, "URL", string1)
print(string)
print(string1) # here I want to URL too not "URL/other part of the url"
```

Comment: Should be fine if you fix the unescaped forward slashes:
`regex = r"https:\/\/amzn.to\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+" + "|" + r"https:\/\/www.amazon.it\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+"`

Comment: @dc-ddfe
Sorry for the late response but this does not work, still see the string"URL" with the other parts of the amazon url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your regex statement with the following:

```
regex = r"https://amzn.to/[a-zA-Z0-9]+" + "|" + r"https://www.amazon.it/.*"
```

The regex, `https://www.amazon.it/.*` means any character after `https://www.amazon.it/`.

**Demo**:

```
import re
regex = r"https://amzn.to/[a-zA-Z0-9]+" + "|" + r"https://www.amazon.it/.*"

string="https://amzn.to/3Ueforw"
string1="https://www.amazon.it/dp/B08F9LM1FB/?tag=seller050-21&psc=1"
string = re.sub(regex, "URL", string)
string1 = re.sub(regex, "URL", string1)
print(string)
print(string1) # here I want to URL too not "URL/other part of the url"
```

**Output**:

```
URL
URL
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update your regex, Just to explain - I have written regex which includes both amazon domain uses non-greedy with any char match with a single line

```
    import re
regex = r"(https://amzn\.to/.*)|(https://www.amazon\.it/.*)"

string="https://amzn.to/3Ueforw"
string1="https://www.amazon.it/dp/B08F9LM1FB/?tag=seller050-21&psc=1"
string = re.sub(regex, "URL", string)
string1 = re.sub(regex, "URL", string1)
print(string)enter code here
print(string1) # here I want to URL too not "URL/other part of the url"
```

Comment: I copy-pasted the code to try it and the result is still URL/3Ueforw
URLp/B08F9LM1FB/?tag=seller050-21&psc=1
I wanted to print just url without the other things

Comment: I think you have mentioned in the question like "URL/other" therefore I thot of URL/3Ueforw. if you can mention the proper example and output you are expecting then it will be helpful;

Comment: updating my answer with this regex - r"(https://amzn\.to/.*)|(https://www.amazon\.it/.*)"